# Unauthorized to get list of terminals

Tags: adyen

I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized error when trying to use the [management API to get a list of terminals](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/Management/1/get/terminals). I'm using PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod.

Here's what I'm trying to run:

$Key = [API Key]

$Headers = @{'Content-Type' = 'application/json'; 'X-API-Key' = $Key}

$Uri = "https://management-test.adyen.com/v1/terminals"

Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers

Result is this:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri $Uri -Headers $Headers
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

The API library states that the API Credential must have the 'POS Terminal Management API' and 'Management API—Terminal settings read' roles assigned, which it does.

I do get a success code when I try the [API to get company account](https://docs.adyen.com/api-explorer/Management/1/get/companies/_companyId_), so I know the API key works. Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access `/v1/terminals` after granting also the `PSP Terminal Action Management API` role.

Assign to the API credential that owns the API Key the following roles:

- POS Terminal Management API
- Management API—Terminal settings read
- PSP Terminal Action Management API

Comment: Thank you! I don't have that role enabled so I ended up just making it work with the POS Terminal Management API instead of the regular Management API (which seems like the same thing so I don't know why there's 2 different ones).

Comment: The Management API goal is to manage various configurations (terminals, webhooks, API credentials, etc..), indeed offering Terminal Management API features and more.